# Highcharts Drilldown is not show if i have more than 4000 data points

Tags: highcharts

I have a drill down report, which has to show the issues for the selected range of date say 2014 to 2015 till date. More than 4000 issues filed. The report got rendered, but when i drilldown not thing is show(Empty page).

Unable to test with jsfiddle.

What is the max data points that we can show in the drill down?

Comment: if not fiddle,paste the code over here

Comment: Jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/junfc8se/  Max i tried to get this jsfiddle. More then 1000. But i have 4297 data points. I found the http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<column>.turboThreshold turboThreshold in the API doc. Is it related to this.

Answer (score 0):

turbo threshold should be set(by default it is 1000): http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#

```
plotOptions.series.turboThreshold
    plotOptions:{
                    column:{
                        borderWidth:0
                    },
                    series:{
                        turboThreshold:5000
                    }
                },
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/junfc8se/1/)

Comment: Or set turbothreshold as 0, then is no limits.